# Setup script - managing settings

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a auto install script (bash) for FreeBSD machines.  It's dynamic in that I can pass some command line arguments and apply the settings as needed.  This is for writing things like `/etc/rc.conf` or `/boot/loader.conf`, configuring the default `.profile` with custom functions and aliases, etc.

Right now, I'm using arrays to hold the values I need to write, but because there are so many files that need to get modified and so many settings that need to get set, I'm getting a really, really long script.

For example, I currently have 12 different arrays and one of them has 25 elements alone.  I did it this way, because, I really don't know how it's traditionally done.

So, what I'm asking is if/what are other ways of bringing in these settings (or more generically, data) for writing to files programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I understand the BSD folks have a rather dim view of GNU stuff, which includes bash. Consider using their native shell (yes, it hurts....).

Consider having skeleton files with placeholders like `%username%` or `%uid%`,  and so on, and clean up the resulting mess by a search and replace. For flexibility, have a file containing configuration as e.g.:

```
%username% joe
%uid% 1000
...
```

From this it is easy to whip up a sed script to mangle all possibly affected files. That way, adding files with further configuration later on is easy.

As far as possible, have stuff be *data*, not generated by the script.

Comment: I reread my post 3 times following this this answer thinking that erred and mis-stated my problem.  However, from your opening statement re: BSD folks to the last sentence about about stuff being data, none of your answer is related to my question.  If fact most of, if stood on its own doesn’t make sense.  Perhaps you’re thinking of a different question?